# Replace parameter in a url string using JavaScript inside Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to replace a parameter in a url with another using GTM. In the link below, I want to replace amazon affiliate tag ID "bestelectricridesweight-20" with "electricridessg-20"

> [https://www.amazon.com/SWAGTRON-T6-Off-Road-Hoverboard-Certified/dp/B01NH2WD3Z?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAIWWM3HVERXCJ5HLA&tag=bestelectricridesweight-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NH2WD3Z)

I tried this javascript code but it's not working:

```
(function () { 
    var linkss = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="amazon.com"]') //change amazon.com to any domain you want to target
    var searchString = "bestelectricridesweight-20" //the string to be searched for
    var replacementString = "electricridessg-20" //the replacement for the searched string 

    linkss.forEach(function(linkd){
        var original = linkd.getAttribute("href");
        var replace = original.replace(searchString,replacementString)
        linkd.setAttribute("href",replace)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use use [`URL API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and [`searchParams.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) method to change the value of `tag` searchparameter

```js
let parsed = new URL("https://www.amazon.com/SWAGTRON-T6-Off-Road-Hoverboard-Certified/dp/B01NH2WD3Z?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAIWWM3HVERXCJ5HLA&tag=bestelectricridesweight-20")

parsed.searchParams.set('tag', 'electricridessg-20')

console.log(parsed.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = new URL(linkd.getAttribute("href"));
href.searchParams.set("tag", replacementString); 
linkd.setAttribute("href", href.toString());
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer